# SoapUI to send and receive large files

Tags: soap, timeout, soapui

I try to send a SOAP request with attachment with use of SoapUI 5.7.0. In server log I see, that request was successfully received and response was sent. Response is also a large file and I get error message in SoapUI:

> Error getting response; null

I have already set following in SoapUI:

File - Preferences - HTTP Settings: `Socket timeout`: 600000, `Max response size`: 0.
`Proxy setting`: None
In test request properties I set `Timeout` to 600000.